# Pyaudio- IOError: No Default Input Device Available

Tags: audio

I'm using A Raspberry Pi with default output(3.5 jack) and a usb microphone. My ALSA configuration is:

```
    pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "plughw:0,0"
    capture.pcm "plughw:1,0"
    }
    ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}
```

When running sopare I get following error:

```
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 949, in       get_default_input_device_info
device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
IOError: No Default Input Device Available
```

pyaudio shows following devices:

```
5
Input Device id 0 - bcm2835 ALSA: - (hw:0,0)
Input Device id 1 - bcm2835 ALSA: IEC958/HDMI (hw:0,1)
Input Device id 2 - sysdefault
Input Device id 3 - dmix
Input Device id 4 - default
```

At a loss on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Set `input_device_index` and `output_device_index` parameters. See the documentation: https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/